# How do I get the progress of an rsync run by a php exec command

Tags: php, exec, output, rsync, progress

I have a shell script (rsync.sh) with an rsync command in it:

> rsync -rtlv --password-file=/path/to/password/file/file.txt --bwlimit=5000 /local/root/path/$1 username@remoteserver::remote/root/path/$2

I then run that from PHP (rsync.php) with an exec command:

> exec('/path/to/shell/script/rsync.sh local/specific/path/ remote/specific/path/', $progress, $errors);

This all works fine.  I get the progress once it's finished and I parse it.  So far I've only been testing on a few smaller files.  However, once this is put into production I am expecting this to be done on several large files that will take over an hour to finish.  I would like to be able to view the progress as it's happening.  If I put the --progress flag in there I'm not sure exactly how I'll get the progress back through the exec.  Any ideas?

I think I'll have to make the exec asynchronous and somehow post the progress to a database where it can be collected and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The PHP `exec()` function does not return until the command completes.

This is really not a very good task for PHP — web servers generally do not cope well with PHP scripts (and, hence, web requests) that take hours to complete. That being said, you will be able to get *closer* to the intended behavior using the [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) family of functions, which allow you to start a process that runs in parallel with a PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That makes sense.  So that means piping the results from the rsync to MySQL.  Is that possible?

Comment: Not directly. You'd have to have some something else involved — a command-line PHP script, for instance.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  How would I go about doing that?  Piping to php?  something like: rsync command | php /path/to/php/script.php

Comment: Ok so I have this working rsync command | /path/to/php /path/to/php/script.php  
However, I can't seem to get the input (rsync output).  I assumed it would come in as $argv[1], but other than the file path $argv is empty.  Is there another way that the input would come in?